# Loading multiple files into cell array

Tags: matlab

Suppose we have directory containing structured data files (text files containing matrix of numbers only).

Is it possible to load them all, no matter what filename they have, into cell array of matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `dir` to get all the files in a directory:

```
fls = dir( fullfile( myFolder, '*.txt' ) );
n = numel(fls);
data = cell(1,n); % preallocate
fot ii=1:n
    data{ii} = dlmread( fullfile( myFolder, fls(ii).name ) ); % read the file using importdata/dlmread/load - whatever works for you
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this saves a lot of time. When loading form same directory, use `myFolder='.';`